# Do loops and convenience methods cause memory peaks with ARC?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, nsstring, automatic-ref-counting, instruments

I'm working with ARC and seeing some strange behavior when modifying strings in a loop.

In my situation, I'm looping using NSXMLParser delegate callbacks, but I see the same exact behavior and symptoms using a demo project and sample code which simply modifies some `NSString` objects.

You can [download the demo project from GitHub](https://github.com/MosheBerman/loopy-leaky-peaky-loops), just uncomment one of the four method calls in the main view controller's `viewDidLoad` method to test the different behaviors.

For simplicity's sake, here's a simple loop which I've stuck into an empty single-view application. I pasted this code directly into the `viewDidLoad` method. It runs before the view appears, so the screen is black until the loop finishes.

```
NSString *text;

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 600000000; i++) {

    NSString *newText = [text stringByAppendingString:@" Hello"];

    if (text) {
        text = newText;
    }else{
        text = @"";
    }
}
```

The following code also keeps eating memory until the loop completes:

```
NSString *text;

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 600000000; i++) {

    if (text) {
        text = [text stringByAppendingString:@" Hello"];
    }else{
        text = @"";
    }
}
```

Here's what these two loops loop like in Instruments, with the Allocations tool running:

[image: Instruments profiling repeating string manipulation]

See? Gradual and steady memory usage, until a whole bunch of memory warnings and then the app dies, naturally.

Next, I've tried something a little different. I used an instance of `NSMutableString`, like so:

```
NSMutableString *text;

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 600000000; i++) {

    if (text) {
        [text appendString:@" Hello"];
    }else{
        text = [@"" mutableCopy];
    }
}
```

This code seems to perform a lot better, but still crashes. Here's what that looks like:

[image: NSMutableStrings being profiles instead]

Next, I tried this on a smaller dataset, to see if either loop can survive the build up long enough to finish. Here's the `NSString` version:

```
NSString *text;

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {

    if (text) {
        text = [text stringByAppendingString:@" Hello"];
    }else{
        text = @"";
    }
}
```

It crashes as well, and the resultant memory graph looks similar to the first one generated using this code:

[image: NSString crashes again]

Using `NSMutableString`, the same million-iteration loop not only succeeds, but it does in a lot less time. Here's the code:

```
NSMutableString *text;

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {

    if (text) {
        [text appendString:@" Hello"];
    }else{
        text = [@"" mutableCopy];
    }
}
```

And have a look at the memory usage graph:

[image: NSMutableStrings seem to work with smaller datasets]

The short spike in the beginning is the memory usage incurred by the loop. Remember when I noted that seemingly irrelevant fact that the screen is black during the processing of the loop, because I run it in viewDidLoad? Immediately after that spike, the view appears. So it appears that not only do NSMutableStrings handle memory more efficiently in this scenario, but they're also much faster. Fascinating.

Now, back to my actual scenario... I'm using `NSXMLParser` to parse out the results of an API call. I've created Objective-C objects to match my XML response structure. So, consider for example, an XML response looking something like this:

```
<person>
<firstname>John</firstname>
<lastname>Doe</lastname>
</person>
```

My object would look like this:

```
@interface Person : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *firstName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *lastName;

@end
```

Now, in my NSXMLParser delegate, I'd go ahead and loop through my XML, and I'd keep track of the current element (I don't need a full hierarchy representation since my data is rather flat, it's a dump of a MSSQL database as XML) and then in the `foundCharacters` method, I'd run something like this:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
  if((currentProperty is EqualToString:@"firstname"]){
    self.workingPerson.firstname = [self.workingPerson.firstname stringByAppendingString:string]; 
  }
}
```

This code is much like the first code. I'm effectively looping through the XML using `NSXMLParser`, so if I were to log all of my method calls, I'd see something like this:

> parserDidStartDocument:
>   parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:
>   parser:foundCharacters:
>   parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:
>   parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:
>   parser:foundCharacters:
>   parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:
>   parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:
>   parser:foundCharacters:
>   parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:
>   parserDidEndDocument:

See the pattern? It's a loop. Note that it's possible to have multiple consecutive calls to `parser:foundCharacters:` as well, which is why we append the property to previous values.

To wrap it up, there are two problems here. First of all, memory build up in any sort of loop seems to crash the app. Second, using `NSMutableString` with properties is not so elegant, and I'm not even sure that it's working as intended.

In general, is there a way to overcome this memory buildup while looping through strings using ARC? Is there something specific to NSXMLParser that I can do?

**Edit:**

Initial tests indicate that even using a second `@autoreleasepool{...}` doesn't seem to fix the issue.

The objects have to go *somewhere* in memory while thwy exist, and they're still there until the end of the runloop, when the autorelease pools can drain.

This doesn't fix anything in the strings situation as far as NSXMLParser goes, it might, because the loop is spread across method calls - need to test further.

(Note that I call this a memory peak, because in theory, ARC will clean up memory at some point, just not until after it peaks out. Nothing is actually leaking, but it's having the same effect.)

**Edit 2:**

Sticking the autorelease pool inside of the loop has some interesting effects. It seems to almost mitigate the buildup when appending to an `NSString` object:

```
NSString *text;

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 600000000; i++) {

        @autoreleasepool {
            if (text) {
                text = [text stringByAppendingString:@" Hello"];
            }else{
                text = [@"" mutableCopy];
            }
        }
    }
```

The Allocations trace looks like so:

[image]

I do notice a gradual buildup of memory over time, but it's to the tune of about a 150 kilobytes, not the 350 megabytes seen earlier. However, this code, using `NSMutableString` behaves the same as it did without the autorelease pool:

```
NSMutableString *text;

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 600000000; i++) {

        @autoreleasepool {
            if (text) {
                [text appendString:@" Hello"];
            }else{
                text = [@"" mutableCopy];
            }
        }
    }
```

And the Allocations trace:

[image: NSMutableString is apparently immune to the autorelease pool]

It would appear that NSMutableString is apparently immune to the autorelease pool. I'm not sure why, but at first guess, I'd tie this in with what we saw earlier, that `NSMutableString` can handle about a million iterations on its own, whereas `NSString` cannot.

So, what's the correct way of resolving this?

Comment: In each case you're using an uninitialized local variable. Aren't you getting a compiler warning for this?

Comment: @NicholasRiley Nope, no warning.

Comment: With the NSString technique, creating newText is allocating a new and increasingly large NSString each time through the loop, then autoreleasing the old one. Appending to an NSMutableString doesn't allocate a new NSString, so there's nothing to release. It's working as expected.

Comment: You're using the variable once, on the first iteration of the loop, before it has been initialized.  I do get a compiler warning: bookworm% clang -Weverything -framework Foundation foo.m    
foo.m:10:11: warning: variable 'text' may be uninitialized when used here
      [-Wconditional-uninitialized]
      if (text) {
          ^~~~
foo.m:5:24: note: initialize the variable 'text' to silence this warning
  NSMutableString *text;
                       ^
                        = nil
1 warning generated.

Comment: Just to be more clear [text stringByAppendingString:@" Hello"] creates a new NSString each time. [text appendString:@" Hello"] does not.

Comment: @TerryWilcox - Of course, understood.

Comment: Very Important Question! Simple issue but a performance killer. Was struggling with it for hours. Thanks a lot for this!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are polluting the autorelease pool with tons and tons of autoreleased objects.

Surround the internal part of the loop with an autorelease pool:

```
for (...) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        ... your test code here ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Initial tests indicate that even using a separate autorelease pool doesn't stop the crashes. The objects have to go *somewhere*, even if it's a second autorelease pool, they're still there until the end of the runloop, when the autorelease pools can drain. This doesn't fix anything in the strings situation as far as NSXMLParser goes, it might - need to test.

Comment: Actually, that's not entirely true. There's a behavioral difference between NSMutableString and NSString. See my edits please.

Comment: Hrm -- ok -- I suspect this is a pathological case related to the intersection of a micro-benchmark and the implementation of autorelease pools.   It would be highly atypical in production code to append a zillion strings like that.  Not that blowing up is the correct behavior, but just that you've hit an edge case.   Let me look  at the source.

Comment: Looks like this helps solve my memory issue, but the behavioral difference may or may not be a side issue.

Comment: Try turning on "track live allocations only" in Instruments.  I just tested across both OS X and iOS Simulator (but not the device) and was unable to reproduce growth of permanently allocated memory;  no peaks, either.

Comment: Where is that option? Also, when running in the simulator, I'm seeing allocations to the tune of gigabytes, not megabytes. On the device, I see a similar graph, in megabytes.

Comment: Hit the little (i) button on the Allocations instrument (it is at the left) when the program is stopped and then re-do the run.

Comment: Ok, with "Only track active allocations" turned on, the graph is nearly empty. With it disabled, I see my peaks.

Comment: Here's [the demo on GitHub](https://github.com/MosheBerman/loopy-leaky-peaky-loops).

Comment: As long as the peaks are dead objects, you should be fine.  *However*,lots of short lived objects can be an indication of very serious performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

While you're hunting memory-related bugs, you should note that @"" and @" Hello" will be immortal objects. You can think about it as a const, but for objects. There will be one, and only one, instance of this object in memory the entire time.

As @bbum pointed out, and you verified, the @autoreleasepool is the correct way to deal with this in a loop.

In your example with the @autoreleasepool and NSMutableString, the pool doesn't really do much. The only mortal object inside the loop is your mutableCopy of @"", but that will only be used once. The other case is just an objc_msgSend to a persisting object (the NSMutableString), which only references an immortal object and a selector.

I can only assume the memory build up is inside Apple's implementation of NSMutableString, although I can wonder why you'd see it inside the @autoreleasepool and not when it's absent.

Comment: I'm wondering the same.  I haven't been able to reproduce the same memory growth, though.

Comment: @bbum - I've added my [demo project to GitHub](https://github.com/MosheBerman/loopy-leaky-peaky-loops). You can download it and try it.