# Memory overkill when using NSMutableArrays with large number of elements

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory, optimization, large-data

When working with extremely large amount of elements, I often face problems with memory for some methods and operations. In my case, I have arrays with about 100 000 elements. Several operations cause memory overkill, and I want to know the best way to optimize them.

I'm using using XCode 5.1.1 and ARC is turned on.

Here are a couple of samples:

---

1) Adding large number of elements into NSMutableArray.

I need to add number of elements from array to array if some condition is checked:

```
for(NSString* value in files) {
                if (!condition) {
                    [filesToRemove addObject:value];
                }
        }
```

Number of elements in files is about 50K - 100K. This sample will cause memory overkill. RAM usage will start to increase in arithmetic progression. So, to prevent it I can wrap this into @autoreleasepool

```
for(NSString* value in files) {
               @autoreleasepool {
                   if (!condition) {
                       [filesToRemove addObject:value];
                   }
               }
        }
```

I found a similar question to this issue: [Do loops and convenience methods cause memory peaks with ARC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885053/do-loops-and-convenience-methods-cause-memory-peaks-with-arc)

So, using `@autoreleasepool` can solve this one. Any better solutions?

---

2) Subtracting array from array.

This one is more tricky. I have two arrays, first one is about 100K, second is about 50K, and I need to subtract one from another.

First try:

```
[files removeObjectsInArray:filesToRemove];
```

That'll cause memory overkill. Why is this happening? It seems to me, that `removeObjectsInArray` method has the same behavior as 1). I don't know, how this method works, but I can imagine,that basically, we just go through one array in loop, then go through second array in loop and check if current element from array1 is equal to each element in array2.

In pseudo code, that'll look like that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < files.count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < filesToRemove.count; j++)
    {
       if ([filesToRemove[j] isEqualTo:files[i]])
       {
            [files removeObject:filesToRemove[j]];
            // perhaps break here?
       }
    }
}
```

Am I right? If I'll use this code instead of `removeObjectsInArray` and use `@autoreleasepool` in loops, will that cause the same effect as `removeObjectsInArray` method?

**update:** I've tried this one with @autoreleasepool, but it didn't work. The memory usage is still increasing. Any thoughts about excepting objects from large arrays?

---

**My question is:**

How to solve issue №2?

What's the best way to work with such large amount of data? These arrays usually contain strings values. Perhaps using NSMutableDictionary instead of NSMutableArray will be faster? Because, even if I solve issue with memory usage, the speed of these operations is still quite slow.

Comment: What data is in these arrays?

Comment: I've written in the end: "These arrays usually contain string values" (NSString*).

Comment: Not sure what you are using the strings for, but would it be possible to store the data in CoreData and use that for the manipulation?

Comment: @Flexicoder, I used your idea (actually I used SqlLite database instead of CoreData) and it helped. So I ended up with using a small array of objects, that works with database, as removeObjectsInArray and removeAllObjects work fine at small numbers.